# .NET MAUI Take UI screenshot with replaced text

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a simple .NET MAUI single-page application. I want to take a screenshot of the application when a user press "Take screenshot" but with the replaced text "New text" instead of "Old text".
The user will see on the UI "Old text" and have a screenshot with "New text" (without UI flashes).

[image]

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label x:Name="Field" Text="Old text" ></Label>
        <Button Text="Take screenshot" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>    

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs code behind

```
using Microsoft.Maui;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace MauiApp;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mauiContext = this.Handler.MauiContext;

        var newWindowHandler = new WindowHandler();
        newWindowHandler.SetMauiContext(mauiContext);

        // create a fake window and page
        var page = new MainPage();
        var window = new Window(page);

        window.Handler = newWindowHandler;
        page.Field.Text = "New text";

        var screenshot = await page.CaptureAsync();

        var stream = File.OpenWrite("d:\\Temp\\screenshot.png");
        await screenshot.CopyToAsync(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

After the user pressed "Take screenshot" I got a screenshot which is ok **but UI was changed too! Why?**

Comment: Can you also show `page. Field`?

Comment: if shows "New text" maybe its because you changed it to "New text". Am i the only one wandering if the question makes sense?